# Finding the child widget in a group box

Tags: qt

I have QPushButton object and a QLabel object laid out in a QGridLayout layout. This QGridLayout is set to a QGroupBox object. How do I now retrieve the QPushButton that is effectively present in this group box?
I have tried the following code but it does not return a valid QPushButton object.

```
    QGroupBox *grpBox = 0;
    grpBox = (QGroupBox *)ui.tableWidget->cellWidget(fromRow, 0);
    QGridLayout * gridLayout = (QGridLayout *)grpBox->layout();
    QPushButton *btn = gridLayout->findChild<QPushButton *>("+");
```

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

findChild actually works. It should have been called on QGroupBox object.